# Two questions about cin and cout

Tags: c++, iostream

Creating my own cin & cout is somewhat pointless, so I just curious about how.
I know that cin and cout are instances of istream/ostream class; however, I've tried some declarations like "std::istream mycin"
but didn't work.

Besides, I read a lot of posts saying that cin and cout are global variables, but we have to access them through std::cin or std::cout. My understanding is that global variables are those declared in the global scope, but cin and cout are obviously in the std namespaces. Which part of my knowledge is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If I attempt to answer your question about creating your own cin and cout, how will I know if I was successful?  For example, would `auto & my_cin = std::cin;` be an acceptable answer?  Actually you didn't even ask a question about that, so what specifically would you like to know?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I want to know how to create my own cin/cout object, so that I can use "mycin >> string" to function exactly like "cin >> string".

Comment: Here "global variables" actually means "namespace scope", not the global namespace scope also known as file scope. `cout` and `cin` are global in the sense that they're not restricted to a single function or class or block, but they're not members of the global namespace. See [namespace scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Namespace_scope) for more.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Sorry I am a beginner of C++ and just learn the concept of class. Given that I can create an instance of some class by "someClass myInstance;", why can't I create my own cin by "std::istream mycin"?

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks, your explanation makes it clear to me!

Answer (score 5):

`std::cin` and `std::cout` are not just "instances of istream/ostream class". They are also connected to the C++ program's standard input and output stream.

How that happens, how that's done, is not specified by the C++ standard. Your C++ compiler and library does whatever needs to be done to make that happen, and the exact details of the underlying working is implementation defined. Merely declaring two `std::istream` and `std::ostream` objects of your own won't, of course, accomplish that by fiat. If you're interested, you can do some research and investigation, and determine how your C++ implementation or library goes about doing this, and reimplement it yourself, with your own instance of `std::istream` and `std::ostream`.

`std::istream` and `std::ostream`, by themselves, merely implement formatted input and output extraction operations using an underlying [instance of a `std::streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf). `std::istream` and `std::ostream`'s constructor takes a pointer to an instance of a `std::streambuf` that's used as the underlying input/output source/sink.

So, to summarize, in order to reimplement what `std::cin` and `std::cout` does, yourself, it is necessary to:

1. Implement a subclass of `std::streambuf` that handles the underlying input and output by using your operating system-specific resources to read or write to your terminal.
2. Use your `std::streambuf` subclass to construct an instance of a `std::istream` and/or `std::ostream`.